# Is there any chance that a web service method returns null, if web service returns the names really slow?

Tags: c#, properties, static, lazy-evaluation

I have dumb codes below; School has 2 static members, Teachers and Students, and their lists are populated from web service call in their constructors.

My question is "Is there any chance that GetNamesOfTeachers or GetNamesOfStudents return null, if web service returns the names really slow?"

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
public class School 
{
    private static readonly teachers = new Teachers();
    private static readonly students = new Students();

    public List<string> GetNamesOfTeachers() => teachers.Names;
    public List<string> GetNamesOfStudents() => students.Names;
}
public class Teachers() 
{
    private readonly List<string> _names;
    public List<string> Names => _names;

    public Teachers() => _names = GetTeachersFromService(); // Synchronous call to web service
}
public class Students() 
{
    private readonly List<string> _names;
    public List<string> Names => _names;

    public Students() => _names = GetStudentsFromService(); // Synchronous call to web service
}
```

Comment: The comments in your code say that these are synchronous calls.  The method, of course, is free to return null if it is written to do so, perhaps if an error condition is present or the server times out.  Otherwise, the definition of "synchronous" is "your code waits for the method to finish and return a result."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all depends on how GetTeachersFromService() is implemented. If the method looks like below, then GetNamesOfTeachers will return null.

```
public List<string> GetTeachersFromService()
{
     // Call web service    
     if (webServiceResponse.teachers.count > 0)
          return webServiceResponse.teachers;
     else return null; 
}
```

if above method has `return List<string>();` in else part then you will get not null empty list from GetNamesOfTeachers.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's my understanding - as long as the service is synchronous, I don't think there is any chance to get null.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the webserver does not time out and by the fact that your call is synchronous, those functions should not return null unless it is programmed to return null.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am confirmed that the function won't return null, if it's a synchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, how your client-code (proxy) for GetTeachersFromService() and GetStudentsFromService() is implemented. But usually even if these functions are called synchronously you can set a timeout. If the service does not respond in a specified time you will get an exception that you can handle in your code e.g.

```
try {
     _names = GetTeachersFromService(); // Synchronous call to web service }

catch(Exception ex){
                   //examine if timeout and do something appropriate }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's the exactly I manage exceptions, though there are more status handling.